# Isolation Level using mySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, serializable, isolation-level

I just don't get how I can form this query.

***Question:***

How can I query for Isolation Level using MySQL?

Is it supposed to be like the following?

```
BEGIN;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
START TRANSACTION;

Select ....

COMMIT;
```

Comment: The code, as shown, should be throwing an error: `ERROR 1568 (25001): Transaction characteristics can't be changed
while a transaction is in progress` It is important to actually include any error messages you are getting when you ask a question.  Please edit the question to show what errors, if any, you are encountering.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should set autocommit to 0 to run the commit at the end:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
```

Later, you should set the isolation level:
(For more information about isolation levels read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html)

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

Finally develop the transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
Select ....
/* all queries that you want */
COMMIT;
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

### Question #1: `How can I query for Isolation Level using MySQL?`

**MySQL 5.X**

```sql
SELECT @@GLOBAL.TX_ISOLATION;  -- SERVER DEFAULT SETTING
SELECT @@SESSION.TX_ISOLATION; -- CURRENT SESSION SERVER SETTING
```

**MySQL 8.X**

```sql
SELECT @@GLOBAL.TRANSACTION_ISOLATION;  -- SERVER DEFAULT SETTING
SELECT @@SESSION.TRANSACTION_ISOLATION; -- CURRENT SESSION SERVER SETTING
```

> Note: I was unable to capture the Isolation change during the transaction as the docs notate:
>
> [Subsequent transactions revert to using the session value of the named characteristics.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html)

### Question #2: `How can I use this?`

```sql
-- Capture your autocommit setting from your session.
SET @var_AC = (SELECT @@SESSION.AUTOCOMMIT);
-- SELECT @var_AC;

SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; -- FORCE AUTOCOMMIT OFF
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; 
-- SET YOUR ISOLATION LEVEL FOR THE NEXT TRANSACTION

START TRANSACTION;
-- -- ADD YOUR CODE HERE
COMMIT;
-- IF NEEDED REVERT YOUR AUTOCOMMIT BACK TO WHAT IT WAS BEFORE
SET AUTOCOMMIT = @var_AC;
```

You can also change this on the Server Defaults or your current session like so:

```sql
SET @@GLOBAL.TRANSACTION_ISOLATION = 'transaction_characteristic'; -- Change for all FUTURE sessions.
SET @@SESSION.TRANSACTION_ISOLATION = 'transaction_characteristic'; -- Change for the Current Session.
SET @@TRANSACTION_ISOLATION = 'transaction_characteristic'; -- Change the next transaction setting.
```

More info on [Transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html), [Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_transaction_isolation), & [how they work.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)

> [NOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html):
>   Within all stored programs, the parser treats `BEGIN [WORK]` as the beginning of a `BEGIN ... END` block.
>
> To begin a `transaction` in this context, use `START TRANSACTION` instead.